# Alpine image build hangs on matplotlib

Tags: docker, matplotlib, alpine-linux

I'm sure this was working a few weeks ago. I can no longer install matplotlib on an Alpine base image. A cut down version of my Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    zlib-dev jpeg-dev musl-dev linux-headers build-base g++ python3-dev py3-setuptools libffi-dev cmd:pip3 \
    && pip3 install --no-cache-dir \
    matplotlib mplfinance
```

The build hangs on

```
...
(53/55) Installing py3-toml (0.10.2-r0)
(54/55) Installing py3-pip (20.3.4-r0)
(55/55) Installing .build-deps (20210525.060427)
Executing busybox-1.32.1-r6.trigger
OK: 318 MiB in 91 packages
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-3.4.2.tar.gz (37.3 MB) **<- This never completes**
```

And never downloads the package

The equivalent slim base image works fine

```
FROM python:3-slim

RUN pip3 install matplotlib
```

No issues with slim

The exact same behaviour happens when I try the build on Google Cloud Build

```
gcloud builds submit . --tag=$GCR_TAG
```

I have tried various combinations of leaving off the `--no-cache` and `--no-cache-dir` but it makes no difference

Comment: just curious, why use docker?  why not just use a python venv since that is simpler?

Comment: `"I'm sure this was working a few weeks ago."`  ... Just a shot in the dark:  Are you able to specify matplotlib 3.4.1 ?   And if so, does that work?  (note: 3.4.2 was released just a few weeks ago).

Comment: I'm using docker as this service is part of an API. Also thanks for the suggestion of 3.4.1, I tried that and get the same result